# optimizing runtime on finding the nth perfect power number

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was given a task to write a code to find the nth [perfect power number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power). i wrote the following function to find that number but the runtime is long at high number (above 30). 
you can assume that the input number is within the range of 1-100. 
here's the code:

```
def perfect(n: int) -> int:
    """
    :param n: enter the n'th place perfect power num you'd like
    :return: the n'th perfect power number
    """
    powers = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(0, n**2+1):
        for k in range(0, i):
            for m in range(0, i):
                if m ** k == i:
                    powers.append(i)
                    i += 1
                    break
        if len(powers) == n:
            break
    return powers[n-1]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Rather than optimizing the algorithm you have, you should consider whether there's a better algorithm to use. After all, it's easy to generate all perfect powers directly - the trick is to generate them in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

As with many questions of this type, rather than speeding up the algorithm you have, you should consider looking for a better algorithm.

In this case, what you're doing is iterating through consecutive integers and testing whether each one is a perfect power. Your test for a perfect power could be significantly improved, but there's a better way: since perfect powers are relatively sparse, it's easier to simply generate the perfect powers directly.

And this is easy to do: we could simply generate all numbers of the form `n**k` for a range of `n >= 2` and `k >= 2`. The only problem with this is that we need the perfect powers *in order*.

The key idea in the solution below is to think of the sequence `4, 8, 9, 16, 25, ...` of perfect powers as being the in-order merge of several streams: we take first the stream `4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ...` of squares, and then merge into that the stream `8, 27, 64, ...` of cubes, the stream `16, 81, 256, ...` of fourth powers, and so on.  All we need to do is keep track of the next element from each stream, and when we want the next highest perfect power we scan those next elements and pull out the lowest one, advancing that stream at the same time.

As an added improvement, if we keep the heads of each of the streams in a suitable data structure, we can make it efficient to retrieve the next smallest element without having to search the whole list. One suitable structure for this is a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), and Python's standard library provides the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html) module for forming and manipulating heaps.

Here's a simple generator for the sequence of perfect powers that's based on the above ideas:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def perfect_powers():
    """ Generate the sequence of perfect powers: 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, ... """
    next = [(4, 2, 2)]
    last = 1
    while True:
        power, base, exponent = heappop(next)
        if power > last:
            yield power
            last = power
        heappush(next, ((base+1)**exponent, base+1, exponent))
        if base == 2:
            heappush(next, (power*base, base, exponent+1))
```

At any given time, the heap `next` contains the next element of each stream, with elements in the form `(power, base, exponent)` (so for example the power `125` appears as `(125, 5, 3)`). In addition, whenever we pull a power of two out of the heap (say `2**6`, for example), we add the first element of the next stream to the heap - in this case the stream of 7th powers, starting with `2**7`.

Here are the first 15 elements generated by the above:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 15))
[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 125, 128]
```

And some casual timings, courtesy of IPython, showing that this approach scales well with the number of terms:

```
In [1]: import itertools                                                                                          

In [2]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 15))                                                      
11 µs ± 20.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 150))                                                     
112 µs ± 717 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 1500))                                                    
1.19 ms ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 15000))                                                   
11.9 ms ± 50.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 150000))                                                  
130 ms ± 1.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit list(itertools.islice(perfect_powers(), 1500000))                                                 
1.37 s ± 29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Less than 1.5 seconds to generate the first 1.5 million perfect powers!